# Case sensitivity in PHP DateTime arguments

Tags: php, datetime, case-sensitive

I'm creating DateTime objects using createFromFormat() method. I can't find it specified if the strings for format argument are case sensitive, where it comes to non-numerical parts. My question is about that matter - are the string arguments for DateTime::createFromFormat case sensitive?

E.g.

Is this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('M', 'May');
DateTime::createFromFormat('A', 'am');
```

equivalent to this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('M', 'may');
DateTime::createFromFormat('A', 'AM');
```

@Edit:

I see I should clear out the purpose of the question. Rules are *not* clearly stated in the documentation. Tests are obvious thing to do, but do not show the consistency between systems/versions etc., which is questionable when not specified. I'm asking if I've omitted anything that can prove how PHP works here. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: the source string isn't case sensitive, but the format argument characters are.

Comment: Couldn't you have tried it for youself? It's not exactly a complex script to write to check it

Comment: @MarcB I'm asking about the source string. ,(at)MarkBaker: True, but I'm curious about the specification, not empirical effects.

Comment: did you not see `the source string isn't case sensitive`?

Comment: @MarcB I never said I didn't.

Comment: @Anant That was a kind introduction, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's case insensitive.

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('M', 'May');
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat('M', 'may');

var_dump($a == $b); //True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  a     Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem   am or pm
  A     Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem   AM or PM
```

see PHP manual for this  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: No Am/Pm then? Does it mean there is no general answer to the question?

Comment: This means that to format uppercase or lowercase `AM / PM or` `am / pm` uses only one character is the converter of PHP that should do the rest. The rule is clearly stated in the documentation PHP